# Hypothetical - about making a header for an *existing* static/dynamic library

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I want to learn more about unix/linux and this question popped into my head - let's say I made a static/dynamic library (.a or .so) and lost the c/c++ source code and header file. Default nm output gives me the names of the symbols but I need to know return types and parameter count/types to make a header. Is it possible to get this extra information somehow to reverse engineer a header for a given library?

Answer (score 3):

You tagged C and C++ and the answer varies slightly between the two.

For C++, the method names of classes have type information embedded in the symbol name. You just have to figure how what kind of name mangling the compiler that compiled the library did.

For C, there's no real clean way to do it. You could take apart the assembly and analyze which registers and stack areas are read without having been written to figure out how many parameters a function takes. This would require knowledge of the calling conventions used by whatever compiler compiled the library.

Similarly, you can look at how each parameters is used in the assembly. If you see it being used in a load instruction, it is most likely a pointer of some sort while if you see it being used in arithmetic, it's possibly an integer of some sort.

For the return type, you can check if anything seemingly meaningful is placed in the return register before a return instruction. Again, this requires knowledge of calling conventions for your platform.

Here's an example of how I would do things in ARM assembly.

I know that parameters in ARM are passed in registers r0 to r3 and the return value is stored in register r0. With that in mind, we can begin reverse engineering. Let's take a look at the assembly for two functions and try to work out what the function prototype was.

```
00000000 <func1>:
   0:   e3510000    cmp r1, #0
   4:   0a000007    beq 28 <func1+0x28>
   8:   e0801001    add r1, r0, r1
   c:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  10:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  14:   e4d32001    ldrb    r2, [r3], #1
  18:   e1530001    cmp r3, r1
  1c:   e0800002    add r0, r0, r2
  20:   1afffffb    bne 14 <func1+0x14>
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  28:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

If we take a look here, r0 and r1 are both read before anything was written to it. We can also see r2 and r3 are written to before they were read. We can therefore infer that `func1` has a maximum of two paramaters.

We also realise that r0 is moved to r3 and then used as an address to `ldrb`, which is an instruction to load a byte from memory. Hence, we infer that the first parameter is a pointer. Because the instruction only loads a single byte, we can also tell it might be a pointer to some sort of one byte data type.

The second parameter in r1 never seems to be used except in compare and add instructions so it is possibly an integer.

Before each `bx lr` (a return-to-caller instruction), something is placed in r0 so we infer that the function returns some sort of value.

If this function were presented to me, I'd guess that the function prototype would look something like this:

```
int func1(unsigned char *, int);
```

Original:

```
unsigned int func1(void *, unsigned int);
```

Here's an another function

```
00000030 <func2>:
  30:   e0822001    add r2, r2, r1
  34:   e5c02000    strb    r2, [r0]
  38:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

This one is very easy.

We see that r0, r1 and r2 are all read from before being written to so we can guess that the function takes three parameters. r0 is used as an address to a `strb` instruction (store byte) so it is probably a pointer. Again, it only stores a byte so it is probably a pointer to a byte sized data type.

The other two are only used in an add instruction so are probably integers.

Nothing seems to be placed into r0 at the end so the function either returns the first parameter or doesn't return a value.

I would guess the prototype would be one of the following

```
void func2(unsigned char *, int, int);
unsigned char *func2(unsigned char *, int, int);
```

Original:

```
void func2(char *, char, char);
```

Comment: Oh yes that's right I remember reading somewhere ages ago about info being imbedded in symbol names or something with c++ but it went way over my head at the time. I actually use c++ not c but was reading a c book when I discovered this. 

I recompiled my test code now with g++ and made a .a file and I can see the symbols are suffixed with i and they take ints so that much be what that means. The _Z4 prefix is the (4 byte) int return val maybe? Anyway, THANKS! Very interesting stuff...

Learning assembler is on my todo list but I'm not there just yet. I much more motivated to now, though!

Comment: I'll also include an example

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that caller/callee conventions vary for different processor instruction sets and you are already aware of name mangling while using c and c++ libraries together, you can try the following way:

```
 gdb <executable>
 ....
 disas <function name>
 ....
 Here you can make a wild guess about the type of return value and parameters using the bit size of those values written on stack making use of assembly code.
```